# Dynamically set variables inside function

Tags: python, dynamic, local-variables, keyword-argument

There is some old script I am trying to use, but with different parameters than the ones that are currently hard-coded.

I thought about putting the code into a function and dynamically set the variables inside.

```
def run_test(**kwargs):
    print(locals())
    locals().update(kwargs)
    print(locals())
    print(a)
```

So I update the local variable with all the values that were passed as key word arguments.

However I get an error if I pass a as a key word.

```
run_test(a=2, b=3)
```

It is a NameError, a is not defined.

I don't get it. "a" gets added to locals inside the function but it can't be called. It works with globals, but why doesn't it work with locals?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the script you want to use? What stops you from modifying the script directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `eval()` function to correctly access local variable inside the function:

```
def run_test(**kwargs):
    print(locals())
    locals().update(kwargs)
    print(locals())
    print(eval("a"))


run_test(a=2, b=3)
```

**Output:**

```
{'kwargs': {'a': 2, 'b': 3}}
{'kwargs': {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, 'a': 2, 'b': 3}
2
```

Comment: `eval` is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: @matszwecja Rarely... But in this case, it works. You can run the code and see the output

Comment: It is not about it not working, it's about it being huge security hole.

Comment: @Cardstdani working doesn't just mean generating the right result. Unless you really understand what are you doing, `eval` should be avoided in general.

Comment: @ahsanul-haque I know. But OP doesn't provide any information about why he needs to  access local variables in such that way

Comment: @matszwecja `eval()` might be an inefficient solution. But in this case `ast.literal_eval("a")` doesn't even work. So I think it's the only **option**